# Regular Expression - Extract Data string php long in array

Tags: php, regex

can you help me, have a string

```
(1, '525222313', 1, 'gfdsgsdfgdfsgsdfgfsdg', NULL, NULL),
(2, '789492261', 1, 'cbxbcvwewwwwwww', NULL, NULL),
(3, '1011587562', 1, 'cbcvnnjjjjjjjjjj', NULL, NULL),
```

I want extract in array PHP...

```
$data = [525222313,789492261,1011587562];
```

Comment: What's the problem? It looks like it should be easy to do with `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: If you want to use a non-RegularExpression way, you could try this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d292a0eb17d58c9bd91627f382c9f5fc47ea6f39 (Not posting an answer because it's not a regex response)

Comment: Are you trying to parse a mysql dump with PHP?

Comment: Try `$re = '/\(\d+,\h*\'(\d+)\'/';` see [demo](https://3v4l.org/KVG5H)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str =<<<STR
(1, '525222313', 1, 'gfdsgsdfgdfsgsdfgfsdg', NULL, NULL),
(2, '789492261', 1, 'cbxbcvwewwwwwww', NULL, NULL),
(3, '1011587562', 1, 'cbcvnnjjjjjjjjjj', NULL, NULL),
STR;

if(preg_match_all('/\d{2,}/', $str, $matches))
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 525222313
    [1] => 789492261
    [2] => 1011587562
)
```

Comment: This will match any 2 or more digits.  Which could pluck out unwanted items.

Comment: We could match against the single quotes too: `if(preg_match_all("/'(\d{2,})'/", $str, $matches))  print_r($matches[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str =<<<STR
(1, '525222313', 1, 'gfdsgsdfgdfsgsdfgfsdg', NULL, NULL),
(2, '789492261', 1, 'cbxbcvwewwwwwww', NULL, NULL),
(3, '1011587562', 1, 'cbcvnnjjjjjjjjjj', NULL, NULL),
STR;

$rows = preg_split('@,\R@', $str);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row   = trim($row, '()');
    $line  = str_getcsv($row, ",", "'");
    $out[] = $line[1];
}

print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 525222313
    [1] => 789492261
    [2] => 1011587562
)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, my string this is...

```
     $data = "CREATETABLEIFNOTEXISTS`blocked3`(`id`int(11)NOTNULLAUTO_INCREMENT,`fb_id`text,`status`int(11)DEFAULTNULL,`original`text,`created_at`datetimeDEFAULTNULL,`updated_at`datetimeDEFAULTNULL,PRIMARYKEY(`id`))ENGINE=MyISAMDEFAULTCHARSET=latin1AUTO_INCREMENT=900;INSERTINTO`blocked3`(`id`,`fb_id`,`status`,`original`,`created_at`,`updated_at`)VALUES(1,'525222313',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(2,'789492261',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(3,'1011587562',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(4,'1017826711',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(5,'1055942382',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(6,'1082213165',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(7,'1109407283',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(8,'1137834449',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(9,'1142349901',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL),(899,'100028872278068',1,'canceladosdeianmmanuel',NULL,NULL);";
```

function ...

```
            $rows = preg_split('@,\R@', $data);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
            $row   = trim($row, '()');
            $line  = str_getcsv($row, ",", "'");
            $out[] = $line[1];
            }
```

this result....

```
   Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => `fb_id` [7] => 789492261 
   [8] => 1011587562 [9] => 1017826711 [10] => 1055942382 [11] => 1082213165 [12] => 
   1109407283 [13] => 1137834449 [14] => 1142349901 [15] => 100028872278068 )
```

The first value "525222313" is not found   :(

Comment: Your input is different to your original question.  Try splitting it on VALUES, and either adapting the trim above (add a semi-colon to your trimmiable chars) or using the preg_match_all solution.  If you go with the latter, pick the pattern in the comments, as otherwise you might match an another column/value.